# Como le hago para detener los procesos en android studio al presionar el boton de atras?

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola Tengo un problema y es que tengo una aplicación que reproduce música pero si el usuario pone una canción y no la pausa y se va a otra actividad y pone otra canción las canciones se escuchan al mismo tiempo 
¿Cómo le pueda hacer para cuando le ponga el botón de atrás de mi teléfono se finalice el proceso de la canción?

Comment: Agrega el código a tus preguntas por favor, como iniciaste la reproducción, un servicio o mediaplayer, es importante aportes más información para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar de una mejor manera, revisa [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que cada canción está en un layout distinto, así que supongo (basándome en la poca información que has dado) que si en la función de cada botón para pasar de layout le añades al final el metodo `finish();` debería de dejar de reproducir la canción en el momento que cambia de activity ya que se finaliza ésta.

Si tienes alguna duda sobre lo que he dicho, primero da un poco más de información ya que hay una metodología para realizar preguntas.

Comment: finish() solo termina la Activity, no termina la aplicación o proceso, tampoco detiene un servicio que fue creado en otra Activity. Para aclaraciones sobre la pregunta se pueden usar los comentarios, revisar [answer], saludos.